# Manipulating a Matrix Stored Within Cell Array -- Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a cell array named "output"(dimension = 3 x 6). Each cell in the first row of this cell array has entries which are 1024 x 1024 matrices (type double). I would like to take the mean value of a given ROI within each matrix. For example, I would want Matlab to produce the mean of the region ([100:200],[100:200]) for each of the matrices and save to an excel or .txt.

I am unsure how to proceed in terms of coding this. Please help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to compute a [mean](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) over an ROI for each cell in the first row like so:

```
meanValues = cellfun(@(m) mean(mean(m(100:200, 100:200))), output(1, :));
```

Then you can save this to a file using either [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) (Excel file), [`csvwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) (comma-separated text file), or [`dlmwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) (delimiter-separated text file).

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @itend Accept the answer if this works for you, just so others know :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Will do. I'm new to this platform :)